# How to "save" a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function with an array parameter which contains different values and callbacks.

The aim of this function is to modify one of these callback (the success one's) if it exists in the option array. The modification is to add some actions before executing saved function.

I know that the good word is not "save", but it's hard to explain. So I let you the commented following code which will maybe more clearly.

```
function myFunction(options){
    if (options.success) {
        // I would like to save the function without execute it
        temporaryVariable = options.success;
    }

    // Then I want to modify the function into the array parameter in order to add some actions before to execute the previous callback
    options.success = function () {
        // Some actions
        console.log('Some actions');
        // Then execute the previous callback I've "save"
        temporaryVariable();
    };
    return options;
}
```

Any suggestion how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nearly nailed it:

```
function myFunction(options){
    var temporaryVariable = null;
    if (options.success) {
        // I would like to save the function without execute it
        temporaryVariable = options.success;
    }

    // Then I want to modify the function into the array parameter in order to add some actions before to execute the previous callback
    options.success = function () {
        // Some actions
        console.log('Some actions');
        // Then execute the previous callback I've "save"
        if (temporaryVariable) {
            temporaryVariable();
        }
    };
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Note: There is no need do set `temporaryVariable` to `null`. You could just use `var temporaryVariable;`

Comment: Exact, I was close to the answer. I thought the `var` instruction wasn't useful. Thanks !

Comment: Success function used to have a data parameter (in fact it's an ajax callback).
Do you know if it's also possible to access this parameter?

Comment: It's possible. Either by declaring int in the function, or by using the arguments array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
function myFunction(options){
    var temporaryVariable = options.success;

    // Then I want to modify the function into the array parameter in order to add some actions before to execute the previous callback
    options.success = function () {
        // Some actions
        console.log('Some actions');
        // Then execute the previous callback I've "save"
        if (typeof temporaryVariable === 'function') {
            temporaryVariable();
        }
    };
    return options;
}
```

Some notes:

- Always remember to declare new variables using `var`.
- If you don't know if you will be able to call `temporaryVariable`, better check `typeof temporaryVariable === 'function'` instead of just checking if `temporaryVariable` is truly.
- Since you will need to check if you can call `temporaryVariable`, you don't need to check `options.success` when you create `temporaryVariable`.

Comment: Thanks it works fine! Can you explain me why is it better to test `typeof temporaryVariable === 'function'`?

Comment: Success function used to have a data parameter (in fact it's an ajax callback). Do you know if it's also possible to access this parameter?

Comment: @Fractaliste It's better to check if it's a function because if you only check if it's a truly variable and try to call it but it isn't a function, it will throw an error.

Comment: @Fractalise About the data parameter, it depends. I should see the full code to see where it is declared, or how could you pass it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to create an object, use it as a property bag, then call into the 'current' bag:

```
function myObject(options)
{
   this.options = options;
}
myObject.prototype.changeOption = function(optName, optValue)
{
   this.options[optName] = optValue;
}
myObject.prototype.performAction = function()
{
    // do something with options;
    return this.options;
}

var myObjectInstance = new myObject({'success':true});
myObjectInstance.changeOption('target','someOtherThing');
myObjectInstance.send();
```